# MongoDB: E11000 duplicate key error collection:dup key: { null }

Tags: mongodb

So I want to have a nested schema like this,

```
const somethingSchema = new Schema({
  something: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  objectCanBeNull: {
    type: new Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Then error `E11000 duplicate key error collection` appears when I try to insert 2 documents without `objectCanBeNull`. I found out the problem is with the nulls, so MongoDb takes it as a duplicate and throws that error. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: It's probably because you have created a unique index. Can you also include how you declare indexes?

Comment: Yups.. sparse: true will do.. Thanks man..